# Why is my FILE pointer causing an undefined symbol error on mac?

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors, stdio

I don't understand why is marking as `identifier "FILE" is undefined`. Firstly I thought it was because of the includes, but in my code I include `<stdio.h>`. Then I thought that it was just a "marking" squiggle, but when I execute in the terminal shows `segmentation fault`, so I don't know what I can do.
Here is my program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("taula.txt", "W");
    for (double i = -0.001; i < 0.001; i += 0.00001) {
        fprintf(fp, "%lf %.14lf \n", i, -pow(i,4)*1/(840)+(i*i)*1/(30)-1/3);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.71.2 (Universal), clang as compiler and the OS I use is macOS Monterey 12.6 in MacBook Pro with M1 Pro.
I hope someone can solve my problem.

Comment: all of your constants are ints. Change them to floats with .0

Comment: Check your fopen() mode.

Comment: Your code compiles fine under clang on my Mac.

Comment: You're right, including `<stdio.h>` should be all it takes to properly define `FILE`.  So there's something strange going on here, but it's not obvious, and it may depend on some strange factor that we don't know about.  It's not because of anything in the C code you've shown.

Comment: What Paul Lynch is trying to tell you is that `"W"` is not a valid mode when you call `fopen`.  The mode you want is `"w"`.  C is generally [case-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error reported for `FILE` seems unwarranted. Check these possibilities:

- maybe the compiler cannot find the standard header files, but it should report this as an error too.
- is there is an empty file called `stdio.h` somewhere in your include path?

Note also these problems:

- to open the file for writing, you should use `"w"`, not `"W"`.
- you should test for `fopen` failure, which probably happens because of the above mistake.
- the number of iterations in the loop may not be exactly 200 because of cumulative errors adding `0.00001`, which cannot be represented exactly using binary floating point representation.
- the expression `-pow(i,4)*1/(840)+(i*i)*1/(30)-1/3` seems incorrect: `1/3` evaluates to `0` because it uses integer arithmetics.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("taula.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open taula.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    for (double j = -100; j < 100; j += 1) {
        double i = j / 100000.;
        double i2 = i * i;
        fprintf(fp, "%f %.14f\n", i, -i2*i2/840. + i2/30. - 1./3.);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *there is an empty file called stdio.h somewhere in your include path?* That is quite the obscure, unlikely possibility! But it's all I can think of, either.  It will be interesting to (perhaps) see what the problem actually is.

Comment: Since the OP is reporting a runtime (seg fault) error, they’ve gotten past the FILE issue. It could be that “I don't understand how can I create a FILE pointer” is the real question; i.e. “how can I use a pointer to a FILE struct when I haven’t declared one?”

Comment: xaviiser, this is an excellent question, since it’s (hopefully) understood that while fp points to a struct of type FILE, an instance of the struct must exist at fp. The C runtime library sets this up, but it’s implementation dependent. It could be a dynamically allocated struct or one that is defined in the CRT as a variable with persistent scope (extern or static). Or something else, who knows?

And yes, use lower case “w” in the fopen(), and always validate its return.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say why it claims that `FILE` is undefined — on that front, your code looks fine to me, and it compiles without issues (and since you can run it, I assume it must have compiled for you too, which it wouldn't have if `FILE` was indeed undefined).

It does, however, segfault. I *strongly* recommend that you check that the return value of `fopen` isn’t `NULL`, and, when you have found out that it is, that you read the `fopen` manpage carefully, especially the section on what the legal values for the second argument are.

EDIT: And the comment about constants being ints is worth listening to, even if that’s unlikely to cause segfaults.

Comment: I just added an if condition to check if fp is NULL, and that why happen the segmentation fault, but then I don't understand how can I create a FILE pointer...

Comment: Again, check fopen()'s second argument, the file mode.